# Distorted label text when resizing

Tags: c#, winforms, text, resize, label

I have a dynamic window with labels on it. The window is a HUD and changes size depending on its parent window. However, one of the labels becomes distorted when resized.

[image: Label bug]

The font of the labels are resized according to the screen size like so:

```cs
float fontSize = this.Width / 128 /getScalingFactor();
```

and the scaling factor is calculated as follows:

```
//Gets the scaling factor of the current dpi settings
        protected float getScalingFactor()
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
            IntPtr desktop = g.GetHdc();
            int LogicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.VERTRES);
            int PhysicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.DESKTOPVERTRES);
            int logpixelsy = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.LOGPIXELSY);
            float screenScalingFactor = (float)PhysicalScreenHeight / (float)LogicalScreenHeight;
            float dpiScalingFactor = (float)logpixelsy / (float)96;

            return dpiScalingFactor; // 1.25 = 125%
            //return screenScalingFactor;
        }
```

And the designer code for the labels. There are labels that holds numbers as well and they are using identical settings. However, they don't get distorted but the username label does.

```
this.labelUsername.AutoSize = true;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(this.labelUsername, 2);
            this.labelUsername.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.labelUsername.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.labelUsername.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
            this.labelUsername.Name = "labelUsername";
            this.labelUsername.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 14);
            this.labelUsername.TabIndex = 3;
            this.labelUsername.Text = "Username";
            this.labelUsername.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

I've tried changing some numbers of the font size and scaling factor. I've tried changing some of the settings in the designer code as well. Unfortunately no success so far.

Maybe someone recognize the issue and can point me to what causes this. I'm assuming there is some mis-match with the label and window DPI perhaps. But that doesn't explain why the numbers doesn't get the same problem.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: This is for winforms.

Comment: You're not showing how the Font is set. It looks like you're painting the Text. If that's the case, show that code. It also looks like that the Text is drawn/set to a wrong background color (transparent, probably). Or you're drawing *your* Text over the existing Text. Or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a clarification. I'm building on a open source project which I'm not 100% familiar with.

So after poking around some more I realized that there is another function which also controls the HUD colors. Unless I added a forecolor to my label there as well, I got that distorted looking text.

I'm assuming that this method is called everytime the window is resizing and when my label wasn't updated with a color there, it got a transparent color. However, because the forecolor had been set at startup it showed as a border around the transparent text because it wasn't resized.